# Разбить строку на массив Pascal

Tags: pascal

Имеется строка типа string с тремя словами, разделенными пробелами. Как можно разбить её и занести все три слова в массив?

Comment: Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Алгоритм такой:

В цикле `for` идешь по строке, когда находишь пробел - это означает, что ты нашел конец слова. Помещаешь это слово (от предыдущего пробела или начала строки до этого пробела) в массив и так до конца строки.

Comment: @4per, насколько я помню, в паскале нет такого понятия как динамический массив... Поэтому если хочется динамики, то нужно делать список.

Comment: В pascalabc точно есть динамический массив

Comment: @user31238, если не ошибаюсь, то pascalabc- это не каноничный паскаль. Года 2-3 назад, каноничный паскаль преподавался.

Comment: Так и есть, в pascalabc.net очень много неканоничных фишек.

Answer (score -1):

В PascalABC.Net это делается одним действием:

```
var Words := txtString.toWords(' ');
```

Comment: PascalABC.Net  и Pascal это такие же разные языки, как VB.Net и VB.